# What is the time complexity of the following function

Tags: time-complexity

Calculate time complexity of:

```c
void func(int n)
{
    int sum=0;
    for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for (int j=1;j<=i*i;j+=i)
        {
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
}
```

I think the time complexity is O(n^2) because the outer loop runs n times, and the inner loop runs approximately i times for each value of i, that means the inner loop will run 1+2+3+...+n times, which is O(n^2), however, Google Bard says that the complexity is O(n^3) because the nesting has a multiplicative effect on the time complexity, meaning the actual amount of iterations is

n*(1+2+3+...+n) which is O(n^3)

But how is that possible?

Comment: While O(n^2) is naively correct, the real answer might be O(1) with sufficient compiler optimizations, as nothing is ever done with `sum`, and both loops can be safely optimized away without changing the behavior of the program.

Comment: We are given the code snippet and are asked to analyze its time complexity, so yes, the code can be optimized, but we are talking about this snippet for the sake of education :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculations are correct - it is `O(n^2)`. The inner loop has step of `i` so it will run for ~ `i*i/i` iterations giving `O(n)` for inner loop too.

Comment: Good catch, I had to look twice to see that it's `i` and not `1`

Answer (score -1):

The function contains two nested loops. The outer loop runs 'n' times, and for each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop runs a number of times equal to the square of the current value of 'i'.

The sum of the first 'n' natural numbers is
1
+
2
+
3
+
…
+
�
1+2+3+…+n, which is known to be
�
⋅
(
�
+
1
)
2
2
n⋅(n+1)
​
. For each 'i' in the outer loop, the inner loop runs
�
2
i
2
times.

So, the total number of iterations is proportional to
�
⋅
�
⋅
(
�
+
1
)
2
n⋅
2
n⋅(n+1)
​
, resulting in a time complexity of
�
(
�
2
)
O(n
2
).

Contrary to Google Bard's suggestion of O(n^3), the analysis reveals a quadratic time complexity due to the nested loops, not cubic. Therefore, the correct time complexity is
�
(
�
2
)
O(n
2
).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).